# Type checking for list of uncertain depth

Tags: python, typing

I have a pair of functions that I use for setting lists/sequences input by the user to a certain depth. The code below (slightly simplified example) all works fine. Is there any kind of sensible way to add type checks to it? Like, can types be applied recursively such that it can handle both a list of depth 1 and a list of depth 2? At present mypy is kicking up type checks for the first two assert statements at the bottom.

```
from typing import List, TypeVar, Union
T = TypeVar("T")


def get_depth(
        obj: Union[T, List[T]],
        curr_depth: int = 0
        ) -> int:
    if not isinstance(obj, list) or isinstance(obj, str):
        return curr_depth
    return get_depth(obj[0], curr_depth + 1)


def set_depth(
        obj: Union[T, List[T]],
        target_depth: int,
        ) -> Union[T, List[T]]:
    obj_depth = get_depth(obj)
    if obj_depth > target_depth:
        return set_depth(obj[0], target_depth)
    if obj_depth < target_depth:
        return set_depth([obj], target_depth)
    return obj


assert set_depth([1], 1) == [1]
assert set_depth([[[1]]], 1) == [1]
assert set_depth(1, 2) == [[1]]
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your code runs without issues - what exactly is the problem?

Comment: I'm assuming you're looking for an alternative to the line `obj: Union[T, List[T]]`, where `obj` is either a `T` or a list of `T`, but you'd like there to be an arbitrarily deep nesting of lists of `T`?

Comment: @Grismar - yes - exactly - the problem is in the type checking. Note that the first two assert statements are failing in mypy.

Comment: @Georgy - thank you, yes, I guess it does - and the answer is that there is no answer, yet.